# ¿Por qué LinkedList no tiene un constructor con una capacidad de inicio como ArrayList?

Tags: java, lista

Estoy estudiando las Collections de java, las clases que implementan sobre todo de List y Map.

Entiendo la diferencia entre las clases ArrayList y LinkedList y su uso (la primera es más eficaz a la hora de obtener un objeto de la lista y la segunda lo es más a la hora de añadir o eliminar elementos).

Pero revisando la documentación de Oracle y probando código, he visto que no podemos inicializar una LinkedList con un valor x, mientras que si podemos hacerlo con ArrayList.
De hecho, ArrayList inicializa la lista con un array de 10 elementos,

```
var = new ArrayList<Tipo>[10];
```

¿Qué razón hay para ello? Doy por hecho que no es casual sino más bien causal, y aquí es dónde me pierdo.

Comment: Si, exacto. El tipo de la lista es indiferente, con ArrayList puedes crear una lista con un número definido de elementos (si no lo haces te la crea con 10 por defecto) pero con LinkedList no

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, es justo el motivo por el que preguntaba, no encuentro nada al respecto y no acabo de entender el por qué de esa diferencia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El constructor de ArrayList define lo que contiene de la siguiente forma:

```
/**
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA
 * will be expanded to DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
 */
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access

public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity > 0) {
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    }
}
```

Como vemos ahi, los objetos de la lista se guardan en un array de objetos. el array, debe tener una capacidad por defecto al crearla.

Ahora, el constructor de la Lista Enlazada, esta definido de la siguiente manera:

```
public LinkedList() {
}
```

Y esto porque?

Porque los elementos de la lista estan definidos asi:

```
transient int size = 0;

/**
 * Pointer to first node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (first.prev == null && first.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> first;

/**
 * Pointer to last node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (last.next == null && last.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> last;
```

Y Node, que no logre encontrar por ningun lado, pero por como se usa, es una estructura que contiene solo un dato de algun tipo (hasta podria contener otra lista adentro), mas un puntero al item posterior y otro al anterior.

todo esto se desprende del codigo de como construye un nuevo nodo:

```
/**
 * Inserts element e before non-null Node succ.
 */
void linkBefore(E e, Node<E> succ) {
    // assert succ != null;
    final Node<E> pred = succ.prev;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(pred, e, succ); <--- ACA
    succ.prev = newNode;
    if (pred == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        pred.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
 }
```

Por lo tanto, no necesita crear nodos con anterioridad, porque la lista ya sabe que tiene y que no tiene antes de llenarse, y crea nodos a medida que los va necesitando.

El Array, como es un array en memoria, necesita ubicar con anterioridad un espacio contiguo de memoria para crearse, y por eso necesita una capacidad.

La definicion de node estaba en el mismo paquete:

```
 private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

[El codigo fuente de estas clases en java aca](https://github.com/ZenOfAutumn/jdk8)

Comment: Fantástica respuesta @gbianchi.
Es justo lo que preguntaba y la respuesta, a pesar de tener que releerme de nuevo los códigos, es totalmente lógica.
Como todo array debe inicializarse, ArrayList también debe hacerlo, mientras que una lista no necesita tener una capacidad previa pues pecisamente su uso es para ir implementando elementos y, al no ser LinkedList tratado como un array (es una lista enlazada a base de nodos pre-post) no es necesaria ni útil su inicialización con un valor!!
Gracias!!!

Comment: @gbianchi aquí puedes consultar la implementación de la clase estática privada [`Node`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l970)

Comment: @Rastajuan leiste el [tour]?? recuerda como funciona el sitio, acepta las respuestas una vez que estan correctas (veo que no lo hiciste con la anterior que hiciste, por eso te lo recalco) ;)

Comment: gracias @AngelOropeza, no se como se me paso..

Comment: Lo había leído pero llevo poco en el sitio y voy haciéndome conel funcionamiento. Entiendo que solo debo puntuar una única respuesta correcta y cuando esta esté finalizada. Poco a poco voy metiéndome en el funcionamiento correcto del sitio. Tomo nota, gracias por tu respuesta y el 'tironcillo' de orejas

Comment: @Rastajuan Puedes puntuar tantas respuestas como quieras, en cualquier pregunta, usando las flechas, aunque sean sobre la misma pregunta y aunque no sean preguntas tuyas. Si la respuesta sirvio y te parece buena la puntuas. Pero solo tenes que aceptar, en tus preguntas, una respuesta, con el tick que esta debajo de las flechas. De esa forma, la proxima persona que busque esta pregunta, sabra que esa respuesta sirve y esta correcta. Aceptar respuestas tambien sube tu reputacion.